# Can tar verify integrity of untarred files on destination disk?

Tags: tar, checksum

Example:

I create a.tar.gz from the file "a.txt" (so I used the -z option). Let's say the checksum of the file a.txt before it's added to the archive is "abc123".

When I untar and "a.txt" is written to disk, can I make it so tar checks that the checksum of a.txt on the destination disk is "abc123" and fail if it isn't the same?

Comment: Tar doesn't do it itself, but it is possible:  http://www.g-loaded.eu/2007/12/01/veritar-verify-checksums-of-files-within-a-tar-archive/

Comment: If you want to verify the integrity of the tar archive, you might want to examine http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129599/test-tar-file-integrity-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that tar has this ability built in however you could run

```
md5sum -c a.txt
```

After you've untar'd it.

Example:

```
$ md5sum file > a.txt
$ tar -czvf a.tgz /etc/hosts
$ tar -xzvf a.tgz
$ md5sum -c a.txt 
file: OK
```

Comment: I would probably distribute `a.txt` (the file with the checksum in it) separately from the `tar` archive. If the archive is corrupt or compromised in any way, you can't trust a hash stored in that same archive to remain correct.